# Copy-PnPFile PowerShell online but with different site collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, onedrive-for-business, pnp-powershell

I am writing a powershell script to copy files (documents) from a OneDrive site to a SharePoint site. They are in different site collections.

I am using this command:

```
Copy-PnPFile -SourceUrl $file.fieldvalues.FileRef -TargetUrl $destpath -OverwriteIfAlreadyExists -Force -ErrorVariable errors -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

But it is giving me 404 error. I think the error is coming from the `-sourceurl` parameter since they are from different site collection. I tried adding the whole url of the source file but it gave me this error:

> Copy-PnPFile : Value does not fall within the expected range.

I can just load the files using `$docLibrary = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents")`, but I'm not sure how to copy its contents to the SharePoint site. Is there any possible approach?

P.S: I am getting the files form the onedrive using   `$items = Get-PnPListItem -List Documents -PageSize 1000`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the file in the local folder in computer firstly and then upload the file from the local folder to the document library in SharePoint online.

More references:

SharePoint Online : Upload recursive files to Document library using PowerShell.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/39980.sharepoint-online-upload-recursive-files-to-document-library-using-powershell.aspx

SharePoint Online: Files operation with PnP Powershell.

https://malcolm1215.wordpress.com/2017/01/05/pnpfilesoperation/

Comment: Thank you!! i've done exactly this one and its working perf. however, just a quick question. we can copy files from one drive to other site collections manually through the list UI but not sure why there are no powershell command for it. or i am completely missing out on this